# Using SSH, search a file for a string and return the value next to it in the last occurence

Tags: python, ssh, scp

I am trying to find a way to extract a value for a Monitoring Data file and use it further. Using an SSH connection (with password) i would like to access a file which is remotely located. The in this file I would like to search for a particular sensor name. Since this file contains data from lot of sensors and from different timesteps, I would like to pick the last (latest) string and next to this string is the sensor value and I would like to copy it and write it in a local data file and use it further in the programming. I could copy the whole file from server to local but the whole file is big and the file keeps changing every hour.

**Time              Sensor-name    Sensor-value**

25-05-2018;15:24  t_amb          24.8

25-05-2018;15:24  t_room         21.2

25-05-2018;15:24  G_global       120

25-05-2018;15:25  t_amb          25

25-05-2018;15:25  t_room         21

25-05-2018;15:25  G_global       227.8

For Example in the above mentioned file which is located in an another computer which is connected via SSH port, I would just like to search for the string 't_room' and find the last occurrence of it in the remote file and write the value next to it '21' into a file which is located at a directory locally.

Edit: More or less I want to do a similar thing but instead of a bash script I want to do it in Python :

```
sshpass -piHEM_MT17 ssh 192.168.101.53 "keysight" | egrep "SP_t_5_roh" | cut -d" " -f4 | tail -n 1 > /run/user/1000/temperaturtest.txt
```

Comment: What OS are you on? What ssh client?

Comment: Doing it on the Raspbian OS, so unix and in built eSSH and SFTP type I think. Via SSH it contacts another Raspberry PI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the data to `grep` to select the last line with `tail` containing "t_room", then print the 3rd column separated by space using `awk`.

For example, if your data is saved in log.txt:

`cat log.txt | grep t_room | tail -n 1 | awk -F" " '{print $3}'`

Comment: Hi thanks, just got time now to come back to this problem. I have one small question. If I instead of needing to print the value in an another file, I would like to use the value further in my coding. Does the print function in the solution return the value or should I use return or import ?

Comment: For example does this work ? - P_L1= sshpass-piHEM_MT18 ssh 192.168.10.49:/home/pi/messdaten/mbus_ac_output_$(%Y%m%d%H).mon | grep "SÜ_t_5_roh" | tail -n 1 | awk -F" " '{import $4}'

Comment: @MuthuAlagappanNarayanan In Bash the printed value is not stored, but you can simply assign that to a Bash variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make some small changes, but this could easily work verbatim.

```
import pexpect
import re

def fetch_sensor_last(sensor_name):
    c = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@hostaddress')
    c.expect(': ') # wait for password prompt
    c.sendline('yourpassword')
    c.expect('$ ') # wait for unix prompt
    c.sendline('cat /full/path/to/log.txt | grep %s | tail -n 1')
    c.expect('$ ')
    c.close() # close ssh child process
    tail_output = c.before.splitlines()[0] # get command output

    # regex matches date, time, and sensor value (see www.regex101.com)
    match = re.match(
        rb'(\d+\-\d+\-\d+);(\d+:\d+)\s+\w+\s+([\d\.]+)', tail_output) 
    if match:
        return match.groups()

date, time, value = fetch_sensor_last(sensor_name)
```

Pexpect essentially runs the command you spawn it with in bash, then you simply `.expect('pattern')` to wait for expected (obviously, the namesake) prompts or other text patterns. If you need to retrieve text, the normal way is to first expect the next prompt, then access the bytes object stored in .before to get all the ascii bytes since the last `.expect()` command.

If you need to troubleshoot the automation, I would suggest running the command manually outside of python, then stepping through the process and recording all the prompts you need to deal with (including prompts for rsa warnings and the like), and ensuring you are not missing anything.

Please note that the strings you get from pexpect are all bytes objects, and you can convert them to normal python strings via `bytesobj.decode()`.